# What does payload mean in context of Contextual events in ADF?

Tags: oracle-adf

From this Oracle documentation of [Contextual Events](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2011/11-may/o31adf-352561.html) :

> Contextual events have two parts:
>
> A publisher (or producer), such as a button that raises a named event,
> with or without a custom payload
>
> A handler (or consumer) that listens for a specifically named event or
> a wildcard event, to process that event

What exactly is meant by the term `custom payload` here ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply the "data" communicated between the publisher and subscriber.  So a contextual event isn't just an event, it can also carry data between the two parties.

For example think of a shopping cart application where you have two separate regions/BTFs, one showing the total cost, and the other the actual items to be purchased.  If the user increases the quantity of one of the shopping cart items, you'd want to communicate the cost of the total items to the total cost region.  Thus the cost is the payload.

Answer (score 0):

payload is data of any type String, Map, Userdefined class etc event publisher sends to the event subscriber. Payload is optional.

Thanks,
Peddi